# Is it possible to give JCMD a service name rather than PID?

Tags: centos, bash, centos6, java, service

I need to monitor a service automatically but the PID keeps changing with every restart

so I want to be able to do

`jcmd servicename Thread.print > log.txt`

rather than

`jcmd 2230 Thread.print > log.txt`

Either that, or I want a way to store pid in a variable

```
var =`pidof servicename`  # didn't work
```

It's centos 6.5, I don't have `systemctl`, I use `service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be ok if possible to store the PID in a file and when needed read it from there. I have seen this done in a lot of services in CentOS. Most of them use it to not start a new process in case there is another one already running. Some startup scripts use a combination of getting the PID from the file and getting PIDs from the running processes to notify the user if there is a stale PID file on the file system. The files containing PID are usually saved in /var/run//.pid